# Passing Parameters from one view to another Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, parameter-passing

I'm new with Laravel and there are some concepts that I don't understand very well. I really need your help on this because I've read many many pages, tutorials and stackoverflow solutions and I dont get the results that I need.
I have a list of "patients" shown on a index page from a database.
Here is the code:

```
 @if($data)
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre de Paciente</td>
        <td>Cedula</td>
        <td>Fecha</td>
        <td>Telefono</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Direccion</td>
        <td>Fecha de Creación</td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($data as $row)
        <tr>
        <td>
        <a href="{{url('/care/$row->id')}}"> {{ $row->paciente }}</a></td>
            <!--<td>{{ $row->paciente }}</td>-->
            <td>{{ $row->cedula }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->fecha_nacimiento }}</td>
             <td>{{ $row->telefono }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->direccion }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->created_at }}</td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    @endif
```

What I want to do, and as you can see, the "patient" name is a link, which referese to (in this case)a form.
I want to get two things from this. 
ONE: I want to get the id of the patient I'm clicking on and the name of the "patient" and send it to the form page.
TWO: on the form page I want to show the "patient" name on the top of the form, and have the "patient_id" hidden to save it on the form table (this patient_id will be a foreing key)

This are my current components:

ROUTE:

```
Route::get('/care/{id}', [
'as' => 'create',
'uses' => 'CareController@create' ]);
```

CONTROLLER

```
 public function create($id)
{
    //

    return view ($this->path.'.care',['id'=>$id]);
}
```

VIEW:

```
    <div class="form-group">

    <label for="exampleInputEmail">Paciente </label>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$id}}">

  </div>
```

But whenever I load the page, it shows a blank page and on the url I see the following:

http://hospital.dev/care/$row->id

I really appreciate your help with this.

UPDATE:
THANKS.
Its sending now the id. But when trying to display the form page, it still sends the blank page, and the url is the following:
"http://hospital.dev/care/1"

I dont know if it is something on the controller:

CONTROLLER:
 public function create($id)
    {
        //

```
    return view ($this->path.'.care',['id'=>$id ]);
}
```

how should I pass the id value no to the url but to the view?

Comment: THANKS EVERYONE. ITS WORKING ALREADY. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply concatenate the href:

```
<a href='/care/{{$row-id}}'></a>
```

Once you have passed the id into your route. You can then handle with the route definition and pass it to your other controller.

for example a view that creates dynamic links:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Endpoint</div>
                </div>

                <table class="table table-bordered" id="endpoint-table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>ip</th>
                        <th>mac</th>
                        <th>proxy</th>
                        <th>model</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="endpoint-table-body">
                        @foreach($endpoints as $endpoint)

                            <tr><td><a href="/endpoint/{{$endpoint->id}}">{{$endpoint->id}}</a></td><td>{{$endpoint->name}}</td><td>{{$endpoint->ip}}</td><td>{{$endpoint->mac}}</td><td><a href="/proxy/{{$endpoint->proxy}}">{{$endpoint->proxy}}</a></td><td><a href="/model/{{$endpoint->model}}">{{$endpoint->model}}</a></td></tr>

                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

then in your routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/endpoint/{id}', 'EndpointController@show');
```

then it gets passed to the controller @ function show where you can do some logic:

```
/**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {

        $endpoint = Endpoint::getObjectById($id);

        $e = new \stdClass();

        $e->id = $endpoint->id;
        $e->name = $endpoint->name;
        $e->ip = $endpoint->ipaddress;
        $e->mac = $endpoint->macaddress;
        $e->model = $endpoint->model_id;
        $e->proxy = $endpoint->proxy_id;

        $endpoint = $e;

        $endpoints = array();

        $endpoints[] = $endpoint;

        return view('endpoints', ['endpoints' => $endpoints]);

    }
```

and when you return your view. You can pass it data passed from the function you defined on your controller. In this instance that function is show() on the EndpointController.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the url is `http://hospital.dev/care/$row->id` is because you are using single quotes, so it won't get the value of the variable.

In the list replace:
`{{url('/care/$row->id')}}`
With:
`{{url('/care/'+$row->id)}}`

Comment: You mean double quotes instead of the +?

Answer (score 0):

Here you're echoing variable `$row->id` as a string `<a href="{{url('/care/$row->id')}}">`, you need to print the value.

Since you've got you routes named I suggest you rewrite it like this using [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route) helper:

```
<a href="{{ route('create', ['id' => $row->id]) }}">
```

Here I called the `route()` helper, passed the route name `create` as first argument and the `{id}` that the route expects as second argument.

Another way would be to just correct your method, by moving the variable out of `''` and appending it to the url like this:

```
<a href="{{url('/care/' . $row->id)}}">
```

Period `.` appends a string to another string in php, not `+`

Comment: Its sending the id. But when trying to display the form page, it still sends the blank page, and the url is the following:
"http://hospital.dev/care/1"

Comment: THANKS. Its sending now the id. But when trying to display the form page, it still sends the blank page, and the url is the following: "http://hospital.dev/care/1"

I dont know if it is something on the controller:

CONTROLLER: public function create($id) { //

    return view ($this->path.'.care',['id'=>$id ]);
}
how should I pass the id value no to the url but to the view?

Comment: Well now you've got to write your logic into the `create($id)` method of your controller. You got patients `$id`, you need to query your database for the patient, pass it to the view and do your form stuff in the view.

Answer (score 0):

The link you are using is like id')}}">
so here you are printing the id as a string. But you need to use this like

id)}}">

OR

id}}">